# Removing duplicates Mailitem based on Subject ,body , Recipient name,Received Time

Tags: outlook, c#-2.0, outlook-addin, comaddin, shared-addin

I am using VS 2010 , Dot Net Framework 2.0 . I have created a project in Extensibility->Shared Add-ins for Outlook.

I want to remove duplicate Mail-item based on Subject ,body , Recipient name,Received Time 
I want to know can i use search engine of outlook and remove duplicate or what should i use to remove duplicates.What is the best and efficient way

Please any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I have done to accomplish this task. I don't known this is the efficient way or not?

1) Created a Data-table and Transverse to each mail-item and added the EntryID,Subject etc in the Data-table.

2) Compared each element one by one using Select() on datatable and added this in DataRow [].

3) Then created mail-item using EntryId.

4) and removed or moved this mail-item

For 210 Email this process takes 25 secs.
Please comment and tell me if this can be enchanced.